# Move SP Site with workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, backup, restore

Can I move SP Site to other Site Collection with all the workflows in it?

I cannot use backup Site and restore because it is not major Site Collection this is one Site with sub site. When I did it by Export/Import Site with Full Security it works good, it import Site with all content and Full Security but with out workflows?

I have quite many workflows so I would like to move it by one time not by import workflows to Export to Visio one after the other.

Whether it is possible to do?

Thanks for support,
Andrzej

Comment: SPSite and Site Collection is the same thing. Do you mean an SPWeb?

Comment: Yes but when I try to backup Site Collection SharePoint wants to backup my whole Site Collection but I would like to move some sub Site from this Site Collection.

Comment: Export-SPWeb: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx

Comment: Are you sure that this commend move my Site with workflow in it?

Comment: No probably not, but to be sure you would have to do a full Site Collection backup. This you can restore as a NEW site collection

Comment: Yes but I have already done it by this way (by export and import) and it did not move my workflows?

Comment: What you need to grasp is that you need to do a full Site Collection backup and restore to keep the workflows. This will create a NEW site collection

Comment: Ok, I get it. It is not possible to do that(move sub Site Collection) without backup and restore whole Site Collection?

Comment: Not successfully